# How to change name being exported by EXPORT_SYMBOL in a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have a set of code that relay on a function `foo` exported by module `mod`.
And I have a newer version of `mod` that exports `foo_implementation` instead.
The `foo` became a macro there...

So, the question is: **how to express `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` to export `foo_implementation` as `foo`?**
With minimal changes to the code, if possible...

Would it be ok to change, say

```c
void foo_implementation(int arg) { ... }
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo_implementation);
```

to

```c
void foo_implementation(int arg) { ... }
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo_implementation);

#ifdef foo
#undef foo
#endif
void foo(int arg) { return foo_implementation(arg); }
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo);
```

???

Comment: `void (*foo)()` declares a **pointer** to the function. While calls `foo()` and `foo_implementation()` are *semantically* equivalent, **symbols** `foo` and `foo_implementation` are **different**. Moreover, if `foo` is alredy defined as a *macro*, your declaration is incorrect. `I have a set of code that relay on a function foo exported by module mod.` - Is it allowed to add definition of `foo()` which just calls `foo_implementation()` to this code ?

Comment: I hope, yes :)

I.e. you mean to replace `void (*foo)() = ...` with `void foo() {foo_impl();}`?

Comment: I mean modifying the code, which needs `foo` to being exported (in other words, which **uses** `foo`), not the one which actually exports it.

Comment: Fixing callers is way too sophisticated as there are several `#define`s that make use of this `foo` and I'm unsure I correctly found them all.

So, it looks better to fix callee instead to provide the entry point the callers want to see.

Comment: Just find header, which declares `void foo(void);` for the users, and replace this declaration with `void foo_implementation(void); static inline void foo(void) {foo_implementation();}`. Fixing exporting the symbol isn't an easy task too. BTW, macro `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is defined in [include/linux/export.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/export.h).

Comment: As for `Would it be ok to change` questions - why do not simply trying that?

Comment: Yepp, trying :)

With the fix provided in the question, it's get loaded. Looks like. But the code referencing it still fails.

Have to debug the .ko now :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there were **two** ways:

1. Hackish, proposed in the question. It works somehow allowing you to load a module at least.
2. Normal one :) Just rebuild not only kmod affected, but the entire set of the code that relays on it. This will make the `#define`s to work properly and the problem will go itself without any violence.